# Converting a formula into a SQL query

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter, erd

I am building a system where it would output the total current balance to the user.

I have a three MySQL tables, first a `Members` table where the user data session gets the `Member_ID` second is `Regular_Savings` and the third (The Out Put Table) `Current_Balance`

I have the Math formula how to work out the interest (see bellow)

[image]

I would like `Total_Balance` in `Current_Balance` table to use the output the current balance, I was trying to use the query bellow but think I have made a few mistakes.

**Query And Codeigniter Model Code**

```
function get_bank()
    {
        $this->db->SELECT(`Principle` * (POWER((1 + (`Annual_Rate_Interest` DIV `Compound`)),(`Valid_For` * `Compound`)))) +((`monthly_deposit` * (POWER((1 + (`Annual_Rate_Interest` DIV `Compound`)),(`Valid_for` * `Compound`)) -1)) DIV(`Annual_Rate_Interest` DIV `Compound`)) as fav, $this->session->userdata("Member_ID"));
        $query = $this->db->get('Regular_Savings');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

**Formula**
[image]

All help is very much appreciated,
Thank You.

****************UPDATE********************

As suggested in a comment, I could use PHP, I the code bellow is close I think, but not right, any ideas ?

**Possible PHP solution**

```
<?php
function interest($Principle,$Compound,$Annual_Rate_Intrest,$Valid_For){
    $Accumulated=0;
    if ($Compound > 1){
            $Accumulated=interest($Principle,$Compound-1,$Annual_Rate_Intrest,$Valid_For);
            }
    $Accumulated += $Principle;
    $Accumulated = $Accumulated * pow(1 + $Annual_Rate_Intrest/(100 * $Valid_For),$Valid_For);
    return $Accumulated;
    }
?>
```

Comment: does the math have to be done in a query?

Comment: No, just as long as the user can see there `Total_Balance`. As im working with data base information i thought a query would be the only way

Comment: I'd suggest just doing it in php, getting all the parameters you need from the member id and doing the calculation there.

Comment: hmm, ok. query the infomation from each table and then work it out

Comment: make one query with all the data if you can instead of one query for each parameter, then yes, work it out in php

Comment: Thank you i will update my question with added php +1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104587/discussion-between-william-burnham-and-beep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the shorthands outlined in your table, the calculation should be

```
// p : principal
// i : annual rate interest
// c: compound
// n : valid for
// R : monthly deposit

// calculate the terms that appear twice
$x = $i / $c;
$y = pow ( (1 + $x), ($n * $c) );

$vf = $p * $y + ( ($R * $y - 1 ) / $x );
```

Comment: William, thank you. I will try to convert this into PHP and get it working, as soon as I do that will update your answer with working code to help others then will accept the answer